# How can i resolve this bubble sort problem?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Python bubble sort with a 5 variable list. The user will input the 5 values and the `bubble_sort` is going to arrange them in ascending order, but when I try to run it it gives the error:

```py
lista = list(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: list expected at most 1 argument, got 5
```

This is the code I wrote:

```py
print('Olá!')
msg = 'Olá!'
n1 = float(input('Digite um número qualquer:'))
n2 = float(input('Digite outro número qualquer:'))
n3 = float(input('Digite outro número qualquer:'))
n4 = float(input('Digite outro número qualquer:'))
n5 = float(input('Digite outro número qualquer:'))
lista = list(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5)
def bubble_sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
    return arr


print(bubble_sort(lista))
print('Fim')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are trying to create the list `lista` using the list() function but it expects an iterable as its argument, not multiple individual elements!

create a list containing all the elements like this:

```
lista = [n1, n2, n3, n4, n5]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer it was really helpfull, i understood the concept well!

Comment: @PedroPorto, if this satisfactorily answered your question, you can mark it as *the* answer and get +2 reputation.

Comment: Using the list notation is entirely correct but worth pointing out that *lista = list((n1, n2, n3, n4, n5))* is also valid